# ArcGIS Mosaic to New Raster returning single value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I am using Mosaic to New Raster to combine two rasters that overlap. RASTERONE contains two different values, 0.4 and 1.1 with some areas of no data. RASTERTWO contains a single value, 0.03, in every cell where RASTERONE contains no data.

RASTERONE metadata:

```
Number of bands: 1
Cell size (X, Y): 50, 50
Format: Tiff
Pixel Type: floating point
Pixel Depth: 32 Bit
```

RASTERTWO metadata:

As for RASTERONE save

```
Format: GRID
```

I am combining them using Mosaic to New Raster with the following settings:

INPUTS RASTERS:

RASTERONE (entered into the dropdown first) then RASTERTWO

Raster Dataset Name with Extension: myraster.tif

```
Pixel Type: 32_BIT_FLOAT
Cellsize: 50
Number of Bands: 1
Mosaic Operator: First
Mosaic Colormap Mode: First
```

This returns a raster with a single value across the entire area. The raster's data range shows correctly in the legend: 0.03 -> 1.1. However, the actual raster is 0.03 across the entire area.

Switching the Mosaic Operator setting from "First" to "Last", without changing the order that rasters are entered into the dropdown, gives the same output: a raster of 0.03 across the entire area.

I have used this same process in the past with success.

What are the possible causes of this problem?